# Is there any difference between the C23 _BitInt() and a non-bit-precise integer of the same width?

Tags: c, memory, c23, bitint

The upcoming C23 Standard adds a keyword `_BitInt()` which can be used, as I understand, to define an integer with a specific number of bits. However I could not find much information with regards to the in-memory representation of types declared this way, and any behavior that relates to their in-memory representation such as their size or alignment.

As such, is there any difference in terms of behavior, representation, or alignment requirements between `_BitInt()` types and 'real' integer types of the same bit width? For example, between `_BitInt(32)` and `int32_t` or `int_least32_t`? And is it well-defined to type-pun between them?

Comment: I would have to think that, just like all other types, the actual representation is implementation-defined.

Comment: This seems like a lot of questions for one Q&A. The representation is two's complement as of C23; bit-precise signed and unsigned integer types may have padding; `sizeof` has always included padding bits, and alignment reflects padding bits. The C23 Standard contains a lot of information about bit-precise types; it would probably be better for you to grab a copy of the C23 draft standard and read up on this, then ask individual targeted questions.

Comment: @adabsurdum I could not find much in the [working draft](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3096.pdf) about these topics specifically. I could not find anything about their alignment or size.

Comment: Like any other integer type, they have to have enough bits to represent the value; padding is implementation-defined. Size and alignment follow from that.

Comment: I have been able to find no mention at all of the implementation details of `_BitInt` in [the draft c23 standard](https://www.iso-9899.info/n3047.html).

Comment: @AndrewHenle Me neither. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: There are a couple of non-normative footnotes in 6.2.5 which say that "any statement in this document about signed [unsigned] integer types also applies to the bit-precise signed [unsigned] integer types... unless otherwise noted."

Comment: @user16217248 6.2.6.2p3 of the draft C23 standard I linked to allows for padding bits on all integer types, so there's that.  But otherwise, I'd venture to say the answer in general to your question is, "It's undefined behavior.  Literally."

Comment: @adabsurdum Yeah, my question was a little on the broader side so I have edited to focus the question.

Comment: If you want to experiment with `_BitInt` types, clang supports them starting with LLVM release 14. As of release 14, `BITINT_MAXWIDTH` is 128. As of release 16, `BITINT_MAXWIDTH` is 8388608 (2**23).

Comment: @KeithThompson And even though it's that big, it's still considered a 'scalar type?'

Comment: Much better focus. The bit-precise types have greater integer promotion rank than standard integer types of the same width. I'm not sure exactly what you have in mind for type punning, but `_BitInt(32)` and `int32_t` aren't required to have the same underlying representation because the exact width types have no padding.

Comment: @adabsurdum The `int32_t` is guarinteed to have no padding but `_BitInt()` is not. But how about `int_least32_t`? With regards to type-punning, what I mean is would something like: `int_least32_t a = 10; _BitInt(32) b = *(_BitInt(32) *)a;` invoke UB? I know you can do that if the types are 'compatible.'

Comment: Every `_BitInt(N)` is a distinct type, so I think not compatible with other integer types.

Comment: Perhaps let us wait until C23 is released?  Else all answer are speculative.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Not entirely. The last public draft of C23 is [N3096](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3096.pdf) (PDF, 3.3 MiB). There will be some changes between that and the published standard, but they should be minor.